# UI Merging. What do you think?

Tags: discussion

I started a [discussion on Area51 about the UI merging](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/user-interface-merge). Please participate with the open mind.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would work for the reasons I outline in [my answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128/user-interface-merge/145#145)

Answer (score 0):

Merging with anything else currently out there except UXExchange (a SE1.0 site) is a very bad idea. I still think UI/UX belongs in a forum and not the SE model.

Comment: What part of the SE model do you feel wouldn't fit UI/UX ? For example, I personally prefer UI.SE because it is connected to the other SE sites unlike UXExchange.

Comment: @user2891 - UI/UX is far more often a discussion - not a Q&A type topic. Stack Exchange (1.0 OR 2.0 - so UXExchange is included in that) is a platform for Q&A, not discussion. As such - neither UI.SE or UXExchange should actually exist using this platform - they would both be better served by a forum.

Comment: I see, good point indeed. In that case, a site like Quora may fit your wishes better then.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the answers of both @ChrisF and @Aaronaught.